# How can I set up logic to count the number of occurences in a month for a list of dates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I have dates that look like this:

9/24/13
9/24/13
10/7/13
10/7/13
10/14/13
10/16/13
10/22/13
10/22/13
10/30/13

I need logic in a cell that will count the number of September occurrences.  Then I need the same logic in another cell that will count the number of October occurrences.  I need the finished product to look like this:

Sep-13    2
Oct-13    7

Comment: I'm assuming we are talking about Excel here? should there be a tag associated with it?

Comment: Yes. thank you. It has been added. Also, the cells are A1:A9

Comment: Do you want the month-year and count all in the same cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `=sumproduct()` to do this. Assuming your dates are a list from A1:A50 the following would calculate how many of them occur in October:

`=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A1:A50)=10)*1)`